# Dual citizenship

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, uk-citizens, dual-nationality, jamaican-citizens

I would like to travel from Jamaica to the US for 2 weeks to visit friends and family.

I have a British passport which will have 6 months remaining by my departure date. Therefore I am planning to return using my Jamaican passport.

Is this allowed?

Comment: You mean return to Jamaica on your British passport? I assume the Jamaican one will expire soon? If not, what's the particular reason? You could probably get through Jamaican immigration faster on their passport, I would think.

Comment: As it currently reads, this is a terribly unclear question. Which direction are you concerned about? Which passports do you think you need to use? Where are you planning to return from? and to? Is what allowed? -1 temporarily, if you clear up your question, I'll remove it to a +1)

Answer (score 3):

You don't pass through immigration in the US when you leave, only when you enter. So there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to use your British passport to enter the US, and then use your Jamaican passport to re-enter Jamaica. Also, as a Jamaican citizen, you should be allowed to use your passport to re-enter up until the day of expiration.

Comment: Are you sure about not passing US immigration when you leave?  Last time I departed USA (Boston Logan airport), every passenger had their passports checked and some had it stamped.  I was flying on a US passport, which didn't get stamped.

Comment: I am positive. There is no immigration on flights leaving the US, regardless of where in the US you are. What you experienced was likely airline employees checking your documentation to make sure you had a valid visa, or, immigration officers from the other country doing a pre-screen to make sure you had a valid visa. For example, when I flew from the Philippines to San Francisco, US immigration/security + airlines employees checked to ensure I had a valid visa (I'm a US citizen so not an issue for me), and, they checked my bags for any goods that would fail a customs test.

Comment: Absolutely not.  This clearly was immigration stand.  This was after the check-in - right before the entry into the security scanning queue.  The agents checking passports wore Homeland Security uniforms. I can't vouch for all of the USA - this was specifically in Boston Logan airport terminal E (i.e. international) - the last several times I flew from there.

Comment: TSA is part of homeland security. They check all documents before you go through security, for both international and domestic flights. You can look all over the internet and this forum, but I can assure you that there is no out-bound US immigration.

Comment: @AleksG: Matthew Herbst is right. The U.S. has no exit checks in any border crossing, whether by land, sea, or air. The TSA checks to make sure you are not bringing any explosives, etc. and you are who you say you are for the security of the flight (whether domestic or international); they have no jurisdiction do deal with anything immigration related. Nobody receives an outbound stamp.

Comment: @AleksG CBP (in dark blue uniforms) does sometimes check departing passengers for customs and immigration enforcement, usually at the boarding gate because it is not routine and there's no infrastructure to put departing international passengers through a checkpoint. AFAIK they do not stamp passports when this happens because there is no stamp for the purpose. TSA (in bright blue shirts) checks documents for identity, not status, and if they stamp anything it is the boarding pass, although usually they scribble on it with a pen. This check applies to domestic passengers, too.